# IE7 changing my style when using jquery/jquery UI and <a onclick="show();hide2();hide3;">

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-7, hide, show

I got my code working the way i wanted it to, works perfectly in ie9, chrome, FF, safari, opera, but when i try IE7 (the company i'm developing for uses this on their system) it causes my content div to move up the page, closing the gap between the header and content. i am wondering if its to do with my inline styling e.g.

```
<div id="lang" style="height:200px">
```

here is my code

#### Javascript

```
    function hide(){
      $('#lang').hide(500);
}

function show(){
      $('#lang').show("blind", 500);
}

function hide2(){
      $('#aud').hide(500);
}

function show2(){
      $('#aud').show("blind", 500);
}

function hide3(){
      $('#rep').hide(500);
}

function show3(){
      $('#rep').show("blind", 500);
}
```

#### HTML

```
                    <h3 class="red">
                    <a onclick="show();hide2();hide3();"><u>Language</u></a> - 
                    <a onclick="hide();show2();hide3();"><u>Audience</u></a> - 
                    <a onclick="hide();hide2();show3();"><u>Representation</u></a>
                </h3>
                    <div id="field" style="height:450px">
                        <div id="lang" class="pad" style="height:440px">
                            <h3>
                                Language
                            </h3>
                            <img src="images/language.jpg" alt="language" align="left" class="im" />
                            <p>Each form of media has its own language that we become familiar with and learn to decode
                            in order to understand the text. In print texts such as newspapers we know that words in a variety
                            of formats construct much of the meaning of this type of media. These include the masthead, headlines,
                            body text and captions. Similarly, magazines will use the printed word in much the same way
                            but mags tend to make more use of photos and graphics which we also learn to decode. An image of
                            a celebrity on the front cover will probably appear as a selection from a studio photo shoot, with suitable
                            lighting, cropping, dress code and there is always the possibility that the image has been photoshopped.
                            In terms of listening media there are language elements such as music, voice and sound effects.
                            Film or moving image media is decoded through sound, camerawork, mise en scene, cinematography
                            and editing. Our experience with the media gives us a working knowledge of of all of the above
                            but in order to produce our own media artefacts we need to have a deeper understanding of these
                            language components. This enables us to encode text, images, sound and film to present our own ideas
                            in a way that makes meaning for the intended audience.</p>
                        </div>

                        <div id="aud" class="pad" style="display:none;height:425px">
                            <h3>
                                Audience
                            </h3>
                            <p>This concept has to do with the way we identify, construct and address audiences.
                            It also deals with the ways in which audiences consume texts and the meanings and pleasures
                            they derive from texts. Audiences are defined by factors such as nationality and age. They may also
                            <img src="images/audience.jpg" alt="audince" align="right" class="im" />
                            be understood in terms of the categorisation of social groups. An audience may be an individual, a
                            family unit or a social group in a pub. Texts are encoded to appeal to audiences in specific ways - think
                            of the appeals offered by the range of characters in a soap such as Eastenders or the attractions of
                            the Olympics to a global audience. Any text can be read differently by different audiences. They may
                            approve or disapprove of the humiliation of contestants on The X Factor. The pleasures of the same
                            text may be completely different for different consumers of the text. Think of a programme that divides
                            opinion in your home.</p>
                        </div>


                        <div id="rep" class="pad" style="display:none;height:360px">
                            <h3>
                                Representation
                            </h3>
                            <p>This is central to our understanding of the media. The media do not present the
                            <img src="images/steriotypes.jpg" align="left" alt="steriotypes" class="im" />
                            world to us but they do offer a re-presentation of it.The role of the media is to construct a relationship
                            between the real world and our ideas about that world. We may think we have extensive
                            knowledge of a celebrity but that knowledge is filtered through the media so that we understand the
                            mediated version of that person. We may think we know a lot about David Beckham through the media
                            but this is made up of the image of the footballer, the ad figure, the celebrity husband, the sporting
                            representative for the UK and so on. These are all aspects of a highly mediated construct and the extent
                            to which we can say we know such a person has to be limited. The concept of representation applies
                            not just to people but to nations, values, issues and our sense of self.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

im also using

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<![end if]-->
```

for my ie7 stylesheet

I'm not a fluent javascript/jquery developer and can only do some simple implementation and modification of plugins like nivo slider/shadowbox etc. so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I also forgot to mention that i'm using css3PIE...

thanks,

Finbar

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with IE issues are always tricky. What i do is use a css reset at the beginning, helps be remove all those issues with margins and padding. You could try that approach if you already have not.

Also when you say content div, can you specify what you mean exactly ( as in which part in your html code)

Comment: this is what i mean when i say content div

    <div id="wrap">
      <div id="header">
      </div>
      <div id="cont">
      </div>
    </div>

and no, i've not used the reset style, i will take a few steps back and try it

Comment: So ive tried the reset.css on one of my pages and found that it hasnt helped my issue

Comment: I've figured out how to fix the problem but don't understand why it was happening...

instead of putting a margin on the top and bottom of the content div, I had a margin on the bottom of the header div and one on the top of the footer div.

whatever the reason this has fixed my issue and if anyone can explain what the difference is I would appreciate it.

Finbar